# Будет ли нарушением mvvm, если писать логику представления (например логика кнопок закрытия окна, сворачивания и т.д.) в code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Сейчас разбираюсь с паттерном mvvm и не могу до конца понять можно ли писать логику view в code-behind или нет. Одни говорят то, что code-behind должен быть полностью чистым, другие то, что логику view все же можно писать в code-behind т.к. не является бизнес-логикой

Comment: Да, будет нарушает. MVVM - это про разделение все на слои, которые не связанны друг с другом. То есть, Model не должен зависеть от VM и V; View не должен зависеть от M и VM; ViewModel не должен зависеть от View. Другими словами, ваш проект должен быть таким, что удалив все в XAML, ваш проект должен запуститься и работать (только без UI), а классы Model вы без труда можете подключить к другому проекту. Ну а окно и вся его логика - это View слой.

Comment: Да можно... я бы сказал даже, без этого никак. Без кода ты никак кастомные Panel или Control не напишешь. Некоторые просто путают code-behind у view с model или viewmodel. Но ты не обломишься, если напишешь в каком-нибудь SizeChanged у контрола логику по смене внешнего вида данного контрола...

Comment: В MVVM вьюмодели отвечают за "что отображать", а вид за "как отображать". Но не определяет как пишется вид. "Чистота code-behind" всего лишь рекомендация по максимуму использовать декларативность, а не запрет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы либо неправильно прочитали вопрос, либо неправильно понимаете MVVM.

Comment: @aepot Да, увидев в заголовке "логика кнопок закрытия окна, сворачивания", чет сам себе напридумывал команду в VM, которая пытается закрыть окно напрямую, про это, по сути, и написал.